# How to ignore the Nuxt.js starting question

Tags: nuxt.js

When I run command `npm run dev` in a nuxt project, there'll be a question asked in the log,

> NuxtJS collects completely anonymous data about usage.                                                              23:02:58
> This will help us improving Nuxt developer experience over the time.
> Read more on https://git.io/nuxt-telemetry
> Are you interested in participation? (Y/n)

I want to know how to skip this question when running the project?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As documentation explain: https://github.com/nuxt/telemetry#opting-out

> 1. You can disable Nuxt Telemetry for your project with several ways:
>    Setting telemetry: false in your nuxt.config:

```
 export default {
   telemetry: false
 }
```

> 2. Using an environment variable

```
NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
```

> 3. Using npx nuxt telemetry disable

```
  npx nuxt telemetry [status|enable|disable] [-g,--global] [dir]
```

Comment: I'm using nuxt version 2.14.6 and the `telemetry: false` option didn't work for me. The `npx` option does it for you, hence it didn't work for me either..

Comment: I chose option 2, by creating a `.env` file and placing the environment variable in it.

I'm using Nuxt 3 and only the first two options work. The telemetry `npx nuxi telemetry` command has been removed. In Nuxt 3 the command is `nuxi` instead of `nuxt`. I chose the environment variable option because putting `telemetry: false` in `nuxt.config.js` results in a TypeScript error, because as of now they haven't properly defined the type to include the telemetry option.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt: >set NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1